# How to intercept the request from Spring Interceptor to Node Service

Tags: java, node.js, spring, docker, spring-boot

Here is what I am trying to do:

- I have API-GATEWAY (Which is in **spring-boot**) where I want to use an interceptor to authenticate the request. If the request is with proper credentials it will call the other service (Which is in **Node.js**)
- API-GATEWAY is running on `8765`. I am calling other services using this `8765` only
- There are 4 Node.js services, And I want every service call need to be authenticated in API-GATEWAY's interceptor as a reason I am using `registry.addInterceptor(tokenValidateInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**");`
- Both spring-boot and node.js services are hosted inside docker container.
- I am using **zuul routes** in API-GATEWAY to call other node.js services.
- All the configuration for calling other services are working fine as I am able to hit other services through API-GATEWAY.

For me, the showstopper is interceptor in API-GATEWAY.I observed one strange scenario here that I want to mention

**If the Node.js service is stopped interceptor is working fine.But if the Node.js services are running it's not even executing the Interceptor**, But the call is going through API-GATEWAY and I am getting a required response from Node.js Service.

Here is my Code Snippet:

```
@EnableEurekaClient
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
@Configuration
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private TokenValidateInterceptor tokenValidateInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {

        registry.addInterceptor(tokenValidateInterceptor).addPathPatterns("/**");


    }
```

Interceptor

```
@Component
public class TokenValidateInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {


    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
        LOG.info("#### Starting TokenValidateInterceptor.preHandle ####");

        String apiKey = null;
        try {
            apiKey = request.getHeader("apikey");

            LOG.info("The request come with apikey ======" + apiKey);

            LOG.info("Actual apikey ======" + azureApikey);


}
```

Suggest the changes or tell me If I am implementing something wrong.

Comment: Why dont you use Zuul filters for intercepting and authenticate the request.?? https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/wiki/Writing-Filters

Comment: The API-GATEWAY is performing much more operations in my project like `AD-AUTHENTICTION` etc. So I have to do this operation in API-GATEWAY only

Comment: @PraneethRamesh : Is there any guideline available to configure it for catching one header and perform an operation on it.

Comment: Just create a zuul Pre filter in which you can get the reference of the HttpServletRequest which can be used to get the header you want. Perform the authentication operation inside the filter. I had done this before it had worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try below configuration. It should work.

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry){
        registry.addInterceptor(new MyCustomInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**");
    }
}
```